# Detect connection close event in Python Paramiko

Tags: python, ssh, sftp, paramiko

How to detect when the connection closed by any reason? Is there any event/callback to this?
Below are my partial working code to connect to SFTP:

```
def connect(self, Host, Username, Password, Keyfilepath, Keyfiletype, Port=22):
   self.transport = paramiko.Transport((Host, Port))
   self.transport.connect(None, Username, Password, self.key)
```

If I manually turn off the WiFi during connected state, I receive a log

> Socket exception: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host (10054)

However this is the error from the `Paramiko` library itself. Is there a way I can control it by my code? Thanks

Some background: When user logs in, I will connect them to the SFTP and update a label to *"Server Connected"*. However when the connection drops due to any reason, I do not have a way to update the label to *"Disconnected"*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call [`Transport.is_active()`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/transport.html#paramiko.transport.Transport.is_active) regularly to check, if the connection is still live.

---

*Ntb, by using low-level `Transport` class, you are possibly bypassing host key check, what is a security flaw. You better use the high-level `SSHClient` API.*